# How to map the X rotation of one object to the Y rotation of another object?

Tags: constraints, transform-orientation

I am trying to make the X-rotation of one object directly affect the Y-rotation of a second object.

I tried using the Tranformation Constraint, however I was only able to map the X-rotation of the first object to the X rotation of the second and the same for the Y-rotation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it through the *Transformation* constraint, set your constraint this way (image below). Essentially, in the constraint, choose your controller object as *Target*, click on *Rotation* for both *Map From* and *Map To*. Under *Map To*, as you want X to control the Y rotation, choose ***Y Source Axis > X***, choose the degree amplitude, you can set to -10° and 10°, for both the controller and the object, and enable the *Extrapolate* option so that it extrapolates beyond 10°.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

2 cubes

Right mouse click on y-rotation > add driver

[image]

choose these settings

[image]

and you get:

[image]

Comment: There's a _slightly_ snappier way .. right-click in the Rotation > X field of Cube 1, and 'Copy as New Driver'. Right-click in the Rotation > Y field of Cube 2, and 'Paste Driver'. But.. you may still have to go to the Driver Editor if the relationship isn't 1->1.

Comment: Cool, didn’t know that